# How to use css selector to style last row only?

Tags: html, css

I have a grid in my store that has 3 products on each row. The amount of rows and number of products on the last row is unknown, it could be one - three.  I need a css selector to target the last row, whether there is one product or three. The html is like:

```
 <ul>
     <li>Row One</li>
     <li>Row One</li>
     <li>Row One</li>
     <li>Row Two</li>
     <li>Row Two</li>
     <li>Row Two</li>
     <!-- Last row, could be on, two or three products-->
     <li>Row Three</li>
     <li>Row Three</li>
     <li>Row Three</li>
 </ul>
```

I tried using:

```
ul li:last-child + li
```

but this obviously doesn't work.

Is this possible? here is a demo with the possible scenarios: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jkqry/

thank you.

Comment: `ul li:last-child`? You want the last row or the last row for group of text items?

Comment: In the first and second row there are always 3 elements or fewer ?

Comment: yes, they always have 3 products. its the last row that i need to target

Answer (score 0):

You use last child selector.

```
li:last-child
{
your css here....
}
```

Comment: no this doesn't work, i need the last row. there could be up to three elements i need to target. this only targets the last element.

Comment: What you are saying is not possible with css.You need you do it dynamically with jquery.

Comment: @user2930185 the last-child will apply to every li element that id the last child of its ul parent.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

if I understoodd your question right:

This should be what you are after

```
ul{
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
ul:last-child{
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

and the html:

```
<ul>Row 1:
    <li>Row One</li>
    <li>Row One</li>
    <li>Row One</li>
    <li>Row Two</li>
    <li>Row Two</li>
    <li>Row Two</li>
    <! -- Last row -->
    <li>Row Three</li>
    <li>Row Three</li>
    <li>Row Three</li>
</ul>

<ul>Row 2:
    <li>Row One</li>
    <li>Row One</li>
    <li>Row One</li>
    <li>Row Two</li>
    <li>Row Two</li>
    <li>Row Two</li>
    <! -- Last row -->
    <li>Row Three</li>
    <li>Row Three</li>
</ul>

<ul>Row 3:
    <li>Row One</li>
    <li>Row One</li>
    <li>Row One</li>
    <li>Row Two</li>
    <li>Row Two</li>
    <li>Row Two</li>
    <! -- Last row -->
    <li>Row Three</li>
</ul>
```

See this fiddle please: http://fiddle.jshell.net/HYyxb/

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, can't you put the `li` you want (the last one or whatever it is) a class, then write css for that class?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
ul li:nth-child(6) ~ li{
    color: red;
}
```

Works if you know how many rows are there.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/gymT4/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `last-of-type` selector : `li:last-of-type`
It must works ;)

Comment: no this doesn't work, i need the last row. there could be up to three elements i need to target. this only targets the last element.

Comment: but that wont work because that will target the second to last row if the last row has less than 3 products.